# How do I repair this stair rail hole and screw back in?

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor, patching-drywall

As you can see the screw on the right side is hanging in the air right now . What should I use to fill the hole and screw them back in? Thanks! [image]

Comment: Can you tell what the screws are screwed into?

Comment: i think I see the top of a zinc screw-type drywall anchor behind the other screw.

Answer (score -1):

These work best if the screws are driven into a wall stud vs. a hollow-wall anchor.  It's not clear what you have going on here, but if it's an anchor, or just a screw driven into drywall, then you should relocate to a spot where you can hit the stud.

Patch the hole with some spackle and if needed, you might need some backer as this looks to be a fairly large hole.

Comment: I think a railing that is not anchored in studs is just for decoration..